# Javascript HashTable use Object key

Tags: javascript, object, hash, key

I want to create a hash table with `Object` keys that are not converted into String.

Some thing like this:

```
var object1 = new Object();
var object2 = new Object();

var myHash = new HashTable();

myHash.put(object1, "value1");
myHash.put(object2, "value2");

alert(myHash.get(object1), myHash.get(object2)); // I wish that it will print value1 value2
```

**EDIT:** See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908885/1129332) for full solution

Comment: In ES6, you can use [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties) for this purpose.

Comment: [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Contributor_s_Guide/Private_Properties#Using_WeakMaps)

Comment: Both links above are dead, recent one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a proposal:

```
function HashTable() {
    this.hashes = {};
}

HashTable.prototype = {
    constructor: HashTable,

    put: function( key, value ) {
        this.hashes[ JSON.stringify( key ) ] = value;
    },

    get: function( key ) {
        return this.hashes[ JSON.stringify( key ) ];
    }
};
```

The API is exactly as shown in your question.

You can't play with the reference in js however (so two empty objects will look like the same to the hashtable), because you have no way to get it. See this answer for more details: [How to get javascript object references or reference count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937120/how-to-get-javascript-object-references-or-reference-count)

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HKz3e/

However, for the unique side of things, you could play with the original objects, like in this way:

```
function HashTable() {
    this.hashes = {},
    this.id = 0;
}

HashTable.prototype = {
    constructor: HashTable,

    put: function( obj, value ) {
        obj.id = this.id;
        this.hashes[ this.id ] = value;
        this.id++;
    },

    get: function( obj ) {
        return this.hashes[ obj.id ];
    }
};
```

Jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HKz3e/2/

This means that your objects need to have a property named `id` that you won't use elsewhere. If you want to have this property as non-enumerable, I suggest you take a look at [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) (it's not cross-browser however, even with ES5-Shim, it doesn't work in IE7).

It also means you are limited on the number of items you can store in this hashtable. Limited to [2<sup>53</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307179/what-is-javascripts-max-int-whats-the-highest-integer-value-a-number-can-go-t), that is.

And now, the "it's not going to work anywhere" solution: use ES6 WeakMaps. They are done exactly for this purpose: having objects as keys. I suggest you read MDN for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

It slightly differs from your API though (it's `set` and not `put`):

```
var myMap = new WeakMap(),
    object1 = {},
    object2 = {};

myMap.set( object1, 'value1' );
myMap.set( object2, 'value2' );

console.log( myMap.get( object1 ) ); // "value1"
console.log( myMap.get( object2 ) ); // "value2"
```

Jsfiddle demo with a weakmap shim: http://jsfiddle.net/Ralt/HKz3e/9/

However, weakmaps are implemented in FF and Chrome (**only** if you enable the "Experimental javascript features" flag in chrome however). There are shims available, like this one: https://gist.github.com/1269991. Use at your own risk.

You can also use `Maps`, they may more suit your needs, since you also need to store primitive values (strings) as keys. [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [Shim](https://github.com/Benvie/ES6-Harmony-Collections-Shim).

Comment: This is a solution indeed, I am just wondering how heavy is that JSON.stringify

Comment: @Babibu, it depends on the size of the object. The bigger it is, the longer it will take to stringify it. If storing objects in a simple array is overkill for you, then stringifying your thousands of objects will probably be too.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` is cheap. Really. This is not going to be the bottleneck of your application.

Comment: But beware that it doesn't exactly fill in your original needs: a unique key for every object. As said in the answer, you can't do that.

Comment: @Babibu I edited to add a solution to work around this, and it's "cheaper" than `JSON.stringify`, although it has a little drawback: you need a special property.

Comment: Yeah I think it will do the job. The only problem with your solution is that you manage the id inside HashTable witch is wrong. It need to be in some place that is unique to the application, so I be able to have more then just one HashTable

Comment: Why? Each HashTable has unique object/values in itself, what's wrong about it?

Comment: @Babidu, you write "The only problem with your solution is that you manage the id inside HashTable". So why don't you manage it outside the class? Just define some kind of global variable. It seems you are looking for someone to write a ready-made solution for you. Florian Margaine provided a good start which just needs to be tweaked for your need.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine After working a bit I posted a complete solution

Comment: @Babibu just for the sake of completeness, I added a last method, the one that *should* be used, using WeakMaps. They're not supported everywhere however.

Comment: This is *wrong*. You cannot rely on the ordering of keys in JSON.stringify(). To different objects with the same keys and values are not guaranteed to return the same string with JSON.stringify() (even though they do "most of the time"). See [javascript - Is there a deterministic equivalent of JSON.stringify?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931967/is-there-a-deterministic-equivalent-of-json-stringify) for a better (but not-trivial-JSON.stringify()) string for an object.

Comment: @Peter in reality, JSON.stringify is deterministic on the same implemebtation, as the answer you linked to says. If you really want deterministic order across implementations (which is not needed there), it's trivial to implement.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine I didn't read anywhere in that question that it should be deterministic on the same implementation. That seems to be the case, though. I _did_ however read that [MDN's stringify page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) says "Properties of non-array objects are not guaranteed to be stringified in any particular order. Do not rely on ordering of properties within the same object within the stringification." Even though it works today, there are no guarantees for tomorrow.

Comment: As Peter claimed objects in JavaScript are unordered, that is true. But I guess 'for var i in obj' might not always return the correct order of properties as they were put in object. And I guess stringify uses the same iteration. So why not make a recursive function that reorders the properties alphabetically. And then use stringify?, or if it is not reliable make your own function that writes json!? I've thought about this a lot... And I've tried a similar solution, check it out: http://stamat.wordpress.com/javascript-quickly-find-very-large-objects-in-a-large-array/

Comment: the `.id` addition creates a meaningless hashtable. It requires you to always keep a reference to the exact object you were using as a key when you called `put()`. The purpose of the map is defeated; if you always have a reference to the same object, you should never have to "look it up". You'd be better of keeping a reference to the value you are trying to map. You need the functionality that allows two objects, that are not the same object in memory, to be equivalent. Because that is missing, `get()` will fail for any meaningful use case. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Its 2018 and WeakMaps have much better support now.

Comment: Indeed, much better than in 2012 :)

Answer (score 24):

Here is a simple `Map` implementation that will work with any type of key, including object references, and it will not mutate the key in any way:

```
function Map() {
    var keys = [], values = [];

    return {
        put: function (key, value) {
            var index = keys.indexOf(key);
            if(index == -1) {
                keys.push(key);
                values.push(value);
            }
            else {
                values[index] = value;
            }
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return values[keys.indexOf(key)];
        }
    };
}
```

While this yields the same functionality as a hash table, it's not actually implemented using a hash function since it iterates over arrays and has a worst case performance of O(n). However, for the vast majority of sensible use cases this shouldn't be a problem at all. The `indexOf` function is implemented by the JavaScript engine and is highly optimized.

Comment: To future readers: Note that `Map` is no longer a good name for this since it conflicts with the [built-in `Map` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

Answer (score 11):

I took @Florian Margaine's suggestion to higher level and came up with this:

```
function HashTable(){
    var hash = new Object();
    this.put = function(key, value){
        if(typeof key === "string"){
            hash[key] = value;
        }
        else{
            if(key._hashtableUniqueId == undefined){
                key._hashtableUniqueId = UniqueId.prototype.generateId();
            }
            hash[key._hashtableUniqueId] = value;
        }

    };

    this.get = function(key){
        if(typeof key === "string"){
            return hash[key];
        }
        if(key._hashtableUniqueId == undefined){
            return undefined;
        }
        return hash[key._hashtableUniqueId];
    };
}

function UniqueId(){

}

UniqueId.prototype._id = 0;
UniqueId.prototype.generateId = function(){
    return (++UniqueId.prototype._id).toString();
};
```

**Usage**

```
var map = new HashTable();
var object1 = new Object();
map.put(object1, "Cocakola");
alert(map.get(object1)); // Cocakola

//Overriding
map.put(object1, "Cocakola 2");
alert(map.get(object1)); // Cocakola 2

// String key is used as String     
map.put("myKey", "MyValue");
alert(map.get("myKey")); // MyValue
alert(map.get("my".concat("Key"))); // MyValue

// Invalid keys 
alert(map.get("unknownKey")); // undefined
alert(map.get(new Object())); // undefined
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out :)

Comment: This requires that you always keep a reference to the object you used as a key, when calling `put()`. If you are going to do that, why map the values in the first place; why not just keep references to the values instead? Have you considered what will happen if you have two objects that are equivalent, but not the same object (!==) ? They should hash to the same value, but the `get()` method will fail you for any valid key that is not the exact object used in `put()` since you only added the `._hashtableUniqueId` property to one of them.

Comment: Nice solution!! I've improved this solution by adding _hashtableUniqueId to key using Object.defineProperty and configuring it as not enumerable, so it won't appear in, for example, json requests. Also UniqueID object is not necessary. You can look at my answer for details.

Comment: No @ShawnMoore it will be fine. you will get "101"._hashtableUniqueId equals to some random number

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proposal, combining @Florian's solution with @Laurent's.

```
function HashTable() {
    this.hashes = [];
}

HashTable.prototype = {
    constructor: HashTable,

    put: function( key, value ) {
        this.hashes.push({
            key: key,
            value: value
        });
    },

    get: function( key ) {
        for( var i = 0; i < this.hashes.length; i++ ){
            if(this.hashes[i].key == key){
                return this.hashes[i].value;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

It wont change your object in any way and it doesn't rely on JSON.stringify.

Comment: The problem with this, is it is not a "Hash" table; there is no hashing going on. You just created a misleading wrapper for an array. Also, because of your use of "==", you will get unexpected results when using mixed types as keys http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1997934&seqNum=5.

Answer (score 1):

I know that I am a year late, but for all others who stumble upon this thread, I've written the ordered object stringify to JSON, that solves the above noted dilemma: http://stamat.wordpress.com/javascript-object-ordered-property-stringify/

Also I was playing with custom hash table implementations which is also related to the topic: http://stamat.wordpress.com/javascript-quickly-find-very-large-objects-in-a-large-array/

```
//SORT WITH STRINGIFICATION

var orderedStringify = function(o, fn) {
    var props = [];
    var res = '{';
    for(var i in o) {
        props.push(i);
    }
    props = props.sort(fn);

    for(var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        var val = o[props[i]];
        var type = types[whatis(val)];
        if(type === 3) {
            val = orderedStringify(val, fn);
        } else if(type === 2) {
            val = arrayStringify(val, fn);
        } else if(type === 1) {
            val = '"'+val+'"';
        }

        if(type !== 4)
            res += '"'+props[i]+'":'+ val+',';
    }

    return res.substring(res, res.lastIndexOf(','))+'}';
};

//orderedStringify for array containing objects
var arrayStringify = function(a, fn) {
    var res = '[';
    for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var val = a[i];
        var type = types[whatis(val)];
        if(type === 3) {
            val = orderedStringify(val, fn);
        } else if(type === 2) {
            val = arrayStringify(val);
        } else if(type === 1) {
            val = '"'+val+'"';
        }

        if(type !== 4)
            res += ''+ val+',';
    }

    return res.substring(res, res.lastIndexOf(','))+']';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Peters answer, but with proper class design (not abusing closures), so the values are debuggable. Renamed from `Map` to `ObjectMap`, because `Map` is a builtin function. Also added the `exists` method:

```
ObjectMap = function() {
    this.keys = [];
    this.values = [];
}

ObjectMap.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    var index = this.keys.indexOf(key);
    if (index == -1) {
        this.keys.push(key);
        this.values.push(value);
    } else {
        this.values[index] = value;
    }
}

ObjectMap.prototype.get = function(key) {
    return this.values[ this.keys.indexOf(key) ];
}

ObjectMap.prototype.exists = function(key) {
    return this.keys.indexOf(key) != -1;
}

/*
    TestObject = function() {}

    testA = new TestObject()
    testB = new TestObject()

    om = new ObjectMap()
    om.set(testA, true)
    om.get(testB)
    om.exists(testB)
    om.exists(testA)
    om.exists(testB)
*/
```

Comment: I used a closure to enforce encapsulation—we are creating an abstraction. The underlying data structure should only be mutable using our explicit public interface. This reduces the likelihood of bugs/errors/misuse in application code. We can still debug the internals in the debugger, or add additional convenience methods such as `hasKey()` or `size()`.

Comment: @Peter it just obfuscates understanding by now allowing new developers to actually understand the internals via F12/devtools. You only think you do something good, but actually it prevents understanding and hence THAT leads to bugs.

Comment: The whole idea behind abstraction is that it allows us to reason about the problem we are trying to solve at a higher level. The `Map` defines a contract and allows us to offload a certain amount of mental load. Think of this like any other JS engine builtin. Software systems are all about building abstractions upon abstractions until we can express in terms of “what” we want instead of “how”.  This really is the only thing that prevents large projects (with hundreds of contributors) from collapsing.

Comment: Oh really? I work with a large WebGL/PBR/Game engine on GitHub and it exposes *everything* for debugging purposes. And guess what, it's doing great, far from collapsing. Just don't merge shitty Pull Requests until they fixed the code...

Comment: Sorry, didn’t mean to get personal. You are right—things like core libraries, game engines, kernels, device drivers, etc. all make these kind of trade offs—and for good reason—to maximize performance. This is possible with a highly skilled and disciplined team. What I am talking about is risk mitigation, when you can.

Comment: if you to define variable without `var` keyword, it will not work in strict mode

Comment: I had to implement an 'indexOfObject' method, replacing 'indexOf' (here https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980194/781079) since indexOf only finds same object instance.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you don't want your Object keys converted into Strings, I'm going to assume it's because you just don't want the entire code contents of your Objects being used as keys. This, of course, makes perfect sense.

While there is no "hash table" in Javascript per-se, you can accomplish what you're looking for by simply overriding your Object's prototype.toString and returning a valid key value that will be unique to each instance. One way to do this is with [Symbol()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol):

```
function Obj () {
    this.symbol = Symbol() // Guaranteed to be unique to each instance
}

Obj.prototype.toString = function () {
    return this.symbol // Return the unique Symbol, instead of Obj's stringified code
}

let a = new Obj()
let b = new Obj()

let table = {}

table[a] = 'A'
table[b] = 'B'

console.log(table)      // {Symbol(): 'A', Symbol(): 'B'}
console.log(table[a])   // A
console.log(table[b])   // B
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `JSON.stringify()` is completely awkward to me, and gives the client no real control over how their keys are uniquely identified. The objects that are used as keys should have a hashing function, but my guess is that in most cases overriding the `toString()` method, so that they will return unique strings, will work fine:

```
var myMap = {};

var myKey = { toString: function(){ return '12345' }};
var myValue = 6;

// same as myMap['12345']
myMap[myKey] = myValue;
```

Obviously, `toString()` should do something meaningful with the object's properties to create a unique string. If you want to enforce that your keys are valid, you can create a wrapper and in the `get()` and `put()` methods, add a check like:

```
if(!key.hasOwnProperty('toString')){
   throw(new Error('keys must override toString()'));
}
```

But if you are going to go thru that much work, you may as well use something other than `toString()`; something that makes your intent more clear.
So a very simple proposal would be:

```
function HashTable() {
    this.hashes = {};
}

HashTable.prototype = {
    constructor: HashTable,

    put: function( key, value ) {
        // check that the key is meaningful, 
        // also will cause an error if primitive type
        if( !key.hasOwnProperty( 'hashString' ) ){
           throw( new Error( 'keys must implement hashString()' ) );
        }
        // use .hashString() because it makes the intent of the code clear
        this.hashes[ key.hashString() ] = value;
    },

    get: function( key ) {
        // check that the key is meaningful, 
        // also will cause an error if primitive type
        if( !key.hasOwnProperty( 'hashString' ) ){
           throw( new Error( 'keys must implement hashString()' ) );
        }
        // use .hashString() because it make the intent of the code clear
        return this.hashes[ key.hashString()  ];
    }
};
```

Comment: Why do objects need to implement "hashString()" method themselves? couldn't you just define one yourself? see this: [how-to-reliably-hash-javascript-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559712/how-to-reliably-hash-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @florian, here's a way where the id doesn't need `JSON.stringify`:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = HashTable;

function HashTable () {
  this.index = [];
  this.table = [];
}

HashTable.prototype = {

  constructor: HashTable,

  set: function (id, key, value) {
    var index = this.index.indexOf(id);
    if (index === -1) {
      index = this.index.length;
      this.index.push(id);
      this.table[index] = {};
    }
    this.table[index][key] = value;
  },

  get: function (id, key) {
    var index = this.index.indexOf(id);
    if (index === -1) {
      return undefined;
    }
    return this.table[index][key];
  }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

I took @Ilya_Gazman solution and improved it by setting '_hashtableUniqueId' as a not enumerable property (it won't appear in JSON requests neither will be listed in for loops). Also removed UniqueId object, since it is enough using only HastTable function closure. For usage details please see Ilya_Gazman post

```
function HashTable() {
   var hash = new Object();

   return {
       put: function (key, value) {
           if(!HashTable.uid){
               HashTable.uid = 0;
           }
           if (typeof key === "string") {
               hash[key] = value;
           } else {
               if (key._hashtableUniqueId === undefined) {
                   Object.defineProperty(key, '_hashtableUniqueId', {
                       enumerable: false,
                       value: HashTable.uid++
                   });
               }
               hash[key._hashtableUniqueId] = value;
           }
       },
       get: function (key) {
           if (typeof key === "string") {
               return hash[key];
           }
           if (key._hashtableUniqueId === undefined) {
               return undefined;
           }
           return hash[key._hashtableUniqueId];
       }
   };
}
```

Comment: What if I map one item in two different HashTable maps? You will get duplicated ids... To avoid this I used the UniqueId object. Good one with jsons.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman thanks for noticing that!, fixed the code above. Didn't have that problem in my AngularJS implementation because there was an extra closure in factory method.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/WeakMap) when you can (i.e. when you target browsers supporting it)

Otherwise you can use the following workaround (Typescript written and collision safe):

```
// Run this in the beginning of your app (or put it into a file you just import)
(enableObjectID)();

const uniqueId: symbol = Symbol('The unique id of an object');

function enableObjectID(): void {
    if (typeof Object['id'] !== 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    let id: number = 0;

    Object['id'] = (object: any) => {
        const hasUniqueId: boolean = !!object[uniqueId];
        if (!hasUniqueId) {
            object[uniqueId] = ++id;
        }

        return object[uniqueId];
    };
}
```

Then you can simply get a unique number for any object in your code (like if would have been for pointer address)

```
let objectA = {};
let objectB = {};
let dico = {};

dico[(<any>Object).id(objectA)] = "value1";

// or 

dico[Object['id'](objectA);] = "value1";

// If you are not using typescript you don't need the casting

dico[Object.id(objectA)] = "value1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late, but here's a simple `HashMap` implementation:

```js
Function.prototype.toJSON = Function.prototype.toString;
//taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1249531/how-to-get-a-javascript-objects-class
function getNativeClass(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "undefined") return "undefined";
    if (obj === null) return "null";
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1];
}
function globals() {
    if (typeof global === "object") //node
        return global;
    return this;
}

function lookup(x) {
    return globals()[x];
}

function getAnyClass(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === "undefined") return "undefined";
    if (obj === null) return "null";
    return obj.constructor.name;
}

//taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value#examples
var getCircularReplacer = () => {
    const seen = new WeakSet();
    return (key, value) => {
        if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
            if (seen.has(value)) {
                return "[Circular]";
            }
            seen.add(value);
        }
        return value;
    };
};



function encode(x) {
    if (typeof x === "object" && x !== null) {
        var y = myClone(x);
        x = Object.getPrototypeOf(x);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(y).length; i++) { //Make enumerable
            x[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(y)[i]] = y[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(y)[i]];
        }
    }

    return getAnyClass(x) + " " + JSON.stringify(x, getCircularReplacer());
}

function decode(x) {
    var a = x.split(" ").slice(1).join(" "); //OBJECT
    if (typeof lookup(x.split(" ")[0])) {
        return new (lookup(x.split(" ")[0]))(JSON.parse(a))
    } else {
        return JSON.parse(a);
    }
}


//taken from https://github.com/feross/fromentries/blob/master/index.js
/*! fromentries. MIT License. Feross Aboukhadijeh <https://feross.org/opensource> */
function fromEntries(iterable) {
    return [...iterable].reduce((obj, [key, val]) => {
        obj[key] = val
        return obj
    }, {})
}


var toEnumerable = (obj) => {
    return fromEntries(
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).map(prop => [prop, obj[prop]])
    );
};


//taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474986/how-to-clone-a-javascript-es6-class-instance
function myClone(instanceOfBlah) {
    if (typeof instanceOfBlah !== "object" || !instanceOfBlah) { return instanceOfBlah; }
    const clone = Object.assign({}, toEnumerable(instanceOfBlah));
    const Blah = instanceOfBlah.constructor;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(clone, Blah.prototype);
    return clone;
}

function HashMap(a) {
    if (typeof a === "undefined") {
        a = [];
    }

    a = Array.from(a);

    a = a.map((e) => [encode(e[0]), e[1]]);

    this.a = a;
}


HashMap.from = function (a) {
    var temp = myClone(a);
    //convert to array
    a = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < Object.getOwnPropertyNames(temp).length; i++) {
        a.push([Object.getOwnPropertyNames(temp)[i], temp[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(temp)[i]]]);
    }
    return new HashMap(a);
}

HashMap.prototype.put = function (x, y) {
    this.a.push([encode(x), y]);
}

HashMap.prototype.get = function (x) {
    var t1 = this.a.map((e) => e[0]);
    return this.a[t1.indexOf(encode(x))][1];
}

HashMap.prototype.length = function () {
    return this.a.length;
}

HashMap.prototype.toString = function () {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length(); i++) {
        result.push(JSON.stringify(decode(this.a[i][0]), getCircularReplacer()) + " => " + this.a[i][1]);
    }


    return "HashMap {" + result + "}";
}



var foo = new HashMap();
foo.put("SQRT3", Math.sqrt(3));
foo.put({}, "bar");

console.log(foo.get({}));
console.log(foo.toString());
```

Note that it is ordered.
Methods:

- `put`: Adds an item
- `get`: Access an item
- `from` (static): Convert from a JavaScript object
- `toString`: Convert to string

Minified and without the test:

```js
function getNativeClass(t){return void 0===t?"undefined":null===t?"null":Object.prototype.toString.call(t).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1]}function globals(){return"object"==typeof global?global:this}function lookup(t){return globals()[t]}function getAnyClass(t){return void 0===t?"undefined":null===t?"null":t.constructor.name}Function.prototype.toJSON=Function.prototype.toString;var getCircularReplacer=()=>{const t=new WeakSet;return(e,r)=>{if("object"==typeof r&&null!==r){if(t.has(r))return"[Circular]";t.add(r)}return r}};function encode(t){if("object"==typeof t&&null!==t){var e=myClone(t);t=Object.getPrototypeOf(t);for(var r=0;r<Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).length;r++)t[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)[r]]=e[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)[r]]}return getAnyClass(t)+" "+JSON.stringify(t,getCircularReplacer())}function decode(t){var e=t.split(" ").slice(1).join(" ");return lookup(t.split(" ")[0]),new(lookup(t.split(" ")[0]))(JSON.parse(e))}function fromEntries(t){return[...t].reduce((t,[e,r])=>(t[e]=r,t),{})}var toEnumerable=t=>fromEntries(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(t).map(e=>[e,t[e]]));function myClone(t){if("object"!=typeof t||!t)return t;const e=Object.assign({},toEnumerable(t)),r=t.constructor;return Object.setPrototypeOf(e,r.prototype),e}function HashMap(t){void 0===t&&(t=[]),t=(t=Array.from(t)).map(t=>[encode(t[0]),t[1]]),this.a=t}HashMap.from=function(t){var e=myClone(t);t=[];for(var r=0;r<Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e).length;r++)t.push([Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)[r],e[Object.getOwnPropertyNames(e)[r]]]);return new HashMap(t)},HashMap.prototype.put=function(t,e){this.a.push([encode(t),e])},HashMap.prototype.get=function(t){var e=this.a.map(t=>t[0]);return this.a[e.indexOf(encode(t))][1]},HashMap.prototype.length=function(){return this.a.length},HashMap.prototype.toString=function(){for(var t=[],e=0;e<this.length();e++)t.push(JSON.stringify(decode(this.a[e][0]),getCircularReplacer())+" => "+this.a[e][1]);return"HashMap {"+t+"}"};
```

Also, you can customize the encoder and decoder by changing `encode` and `decode` functions.

As in florian's answer, you can't play with the reference in js however (so two empty objects will look like the same to the hashtable).

Comment: Is this better than `WeakMap` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Dict{
    constructor(){
        this.keys = [];
        this.values = [];
        this.set = this.set.bind(this);
    }

    set(key, value){
        this.keys.push(key);
        this.values.push(value);
    }

    get(key){
        return this.values[this.keys.indexOf(key)];
    }

    all(){
        return this.keys.map((kk, ii)=>[kk, this.values[ii]]);
    }
}

let d1 = new Dict();

let k1 = {1: 'a'};
d1.set(k1, 2);
console.log(d1.get(k1));  // 2
let k2 = {2: 'b'};
d1.set(k2, 3);


console.log(d1.all());
// [ [ { '1': 'a' }, 2 ], [ { '2': 'b' }, 3 ] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use the strict equality operator when looking up the object: `===`

```
var objects = [];
objects.push(object1);
objects.push(object2);

objects[0] === object1; // true
objects[1] === object1; // false
```

The implementation will depend on how you store the objects in the `HashTable` class.

Comment: This is not hashtable, this is bad practis of array list with efficiency of O(n). It's not what I am looking

Comment: There is no built-in hash table in JavaScript so, if you don't want to convert the object to a string, you need to use an array and loop through it. How much data will your table store?

Comment: thousandths,I need to find a solution some how. Converting to string not promise me a unique key.