# indexOf( object) in javascript

Tags: javascript

Error in following code:-

```
var x = [{id: 'abc'}, {id: 'xyz'}];

var index = x.indexOf({id: 'abc'});
```

What's the syntax for above?

Comment: That's not a syntax problem. [Two objects with different references in memory are different in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are only equal to each other if they refer to the exact same instance of the object.

You would need to implement your own search feature. For example:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfObject = function(obj) {
    var l = this.length, i, k, ok;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
        ok = true;
        for( k in obj) if( obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            if( this[i][k] !== obj[k]) {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if( ok) return i;
    }
    return -1; // no match
};

var x = [{id: 'abc'}, {id: 'xyz'}];
var index = x.indexOfObject({id: 'abc'}); // 0
```

Comment: `this[i].k --> this[i][k]`.

Comment: @VisioN You saw nothing! :p

Comment: @Kolink Yeah, yeah, yeah... `;)`

Answer (score 4):

You should pass reference to exactly the same object you have defined in the array:

```
var a = {id: 'abc'},
    b = {id: 'xyz'};

var index = [a, b].indexOf(a);  // 0
```

Comment: It didn't work when i tried it though.

Comment: This is working for me..!!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the array like this:

```
for(var i = 0, len = x.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (x[i].id === 'abc') {
        console.log(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to make sure the pointers are the same for the objects you're trying to look for with `indexOf`

Answer (score 1):

Let's have some nice code here ;)

Underscore.js provides [`where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where), which is also fairly easy to write in pure JS:

```
Array.prototype.where = function(props) {
    return this.filter(function(e) {
        for (var p in props)
            if (e[p] !== props[p])
                return false;
        return true;
    });
}
```

Another (more flexible) function understands either an object or a function as a selector:

```
Array.prototype.indexBy = function(selector) {
    var fn = typeof selector == "function" ? selector :
        function(elem) {
            return Object.keys(selector).every(function(k) {
                return elem[k] === selector[k]
            })
        }
    return this.map(fn).indexOf(true); 
}
```

and then

```
var x = [{id: 'abc'}, {id: 'xyz'}];
x.indexBy({'id': 'xyz'}) // works
x.indexBy(function(elem) { return elem.id == 'xyz' }) // works too
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var o = {}
var x = [o]
console.log(x.indexOf(o))
```

With `x.indexOf({})` you create a new Object the is not present in the array

Answer (score 0):

The following is the most wonderful method:-

```
var indexId = x.map(function(e) { return e.id; }).indexOf('abc');
```

as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16008853/989121)