# In Javascript, how to use object as the key of a hashmap?

Tags: javascript, web

Here is the result in REPL

```
>>a1={1:2}
Object {1: 2}
>>a2={1:4}
Object {1: 4}
>>c={}
Object {}
>>c[a1]=2
2
>>c[a2]
2
```

As can be seen, `a1` and `a2` are different objects. However, `c[a1]` and `c[a2]` will get the same result. Is there a way to use object as the key of a hashmap?

Comment: I hope this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892322/javascript-hashtable-use-object-key/10908885#10908885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only strings can be used as object keys. You could go the hacky route and use `JSON.stringify()` to turn the objects into strings, but your best bet is to use an actual hashmap.

You could use a custom implementation of one, or if your target environment supports it, use a [WeakMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap).

There's also a shim for WeakMap that you can use in environments that don't support it yet:

https://github.com/polymer/WeakMap

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the object to a string. The type of keys in a javascript object should be a string

> Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects
>   cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including
>   a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

You can find the same example in the above link.

```
c[<some_func_to_convert_obj_to_string(a1)>]=2
```

So If you want to use the object as a key you need to convert the object to a unique string.. and there are many answers here for that [Converting object to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string) .  As  Steven Wexler pointed out that JSON.stringify is non deterministic it is better not to use it. I am not copying down those functions again because there is a dedicated SO question for that.

Comment: Using JSON.stringify to create keys can be dangerous because JSON.stringify is not deterministic.

Comment: @StevenWexler Or as the OP wants to use an object to as a key ... it should be converted to a string such that  that string maps only to this object... There is a SO qsn for that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612787/converting-an-object-to-a-string

Comment: The following statement: `JSON.stringify(myObj) === JSON.stringify(myObj)` is not always true because JSON.stringify is not deterministic.  So yes, you can create strings from objects with JSON.stringify.  But it's dangerous to use these strings as keys.

Comment: @StevenWexler Ohh ohk... I am not telling that he should use JSON.stringify ... As already mentioned there are other ways of converting object to a unique string other than JSON.stringify and there is  a SO qsn for that ...