# How to copy object methods in ES6

Tags: javascript, cloning

I want to clone an object using the spread operator. However, the methods are not copied as shown

I am aware you could do Object.Assign() but I am looking for a way to do that using ES6 syntax

The solution at [Deep copy in ES6 using the spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-syntax) concerns deep cloning: I am only interested in copying methods as well as properties

The solution at [How to clone a javascript ES6 class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474986/how-to-clone-a-javascript-es6-class-instance) makes use of Object.Assign()

```js
class Test {
  toString() {
    return "This is a test object";
  }
}

let test = new Test();
let test2 = { ...test };

console.log(String(test));
console.log(String(test2));
```

```
// Output: This is a test object
// Output: [object Object]
```

Comment: use `Object.create` instead of spread. `String(Object.create(test))` works as you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone a javascript ES6 class instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474986/how-to-clone-a-javascript-es6-class-instance)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deep copy in ES6 using the spread syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416020/deep-copy-in-es6-using-the-spread-syntax)

Comment: I would like to pint out that `Object.assign` **was added** as part of ES6. Thus it is kinda the thing you are looking for...

Comment: There is no built-in function in ES6 for this, you should use `cloneDeep()` method in `lodash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
class Test {
  toString() {
    return "This is a test object";
  }
}
```

does not define any *object method* strictly speaking. It rather defines class methods.

You need to attach methods directly to the object as "own properties" in order the spread to copy them:

```js
class Test {
  constructor() {
    // define toString as a method attached directly to
    // the object
    this.toString = function() {
      return "This is a test object";
    }
  }
}

let test = new Test();
let test2 = { ...test };

console.log(String(test));
console.log(String(test2));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it like this:

```js
class Test {
  toString() {
    return "This is a test object";
  }
}

let test = new Test();
let test2 = {};

test2.__proto__ = test.__proto__;

console.log(String(test));
console.log(String(test2));
```

But I dont know, maybe its a bad practice  :/..