# js - shallow copy object, preserve prototype, but don't run constructor

Tags: javascript, copy, prototype, move-constructor

**How do you copy an object, preserving its prototype, without running the constructor?**

Everything below is context if you're wondering why I want to do such a thing, feel free to ignore it and answer the question.

I'm just experimenting with bringing RAII/ownership concepts into javascript (for fun and curiosity).  Surprisingly, I have a solution for destructors that works quite well, but I'm actually stumbling on copy constructors and move constructors.

Specifically, I have a `class FileIO`:

```
class FileIO {
    constructor(filename) {
        this.connection = new FileConnection(filename);
    }

    destructor() {
        this.connection.close();
    }

    move() {
        const copy = _how_do_I_(); //copy of this, without running constructor().
        copy instanceof FileIO; // should be true
        // move connection to copy
        copy.connection = this.connection;
        this.connection = null;
        return copy;
    }

    write() {/* TODO */}
    read() {/* TODO */}

}
```

Ideally, I would be able to do this:

```
function main() {
    const fileIO = new FileIO("./something.txt");
    useTheFile(fileIO.move());
}
```

You can see, I don't want to do `copy = {...this}` because it won't be an instance of FileIO anymore. Also, I can't do `copy = new this.constructor(...)` because I don't want to duplicate the file connection.  Is this even possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Hopefully someone gives me something good before this question gets shutdown.  Fingers crossed!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474986/how-to-clone-a-javascript-es6-class-instance ?

Comment: @James that's it.  I have no clue how I missed that one. Do you think I should remove this one?

Comment: No worries.  We can mark this one as a duplicate.